# Exception in HQL limit query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao

I need to retrieve top n records of a table phone_numbers for which a POJO PhoneNumbers exist with corresponding PhoneNumbersDAO and PhoneNumbersDAOImpl. I tried this:

```
public List<PhoneNumbers> getNPhoneNumbersFromMthRow(int m, int n){
    Query query= getSession().createQuery("from PhoneNumbers");
    query.setFirstResult(m);
    query.setMaxResults(n);
    List<PhoneNumbers> lstPhoneNumbers = (List<PhoneNumbers>) query.list();
    return lstPhoneNumbers; 
}
```

However, this raises a null pointer exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSession(HibernateDaoSupport.java:143)
at com.pw.dao.PhoneNumbersDAOImpl.getNPhoneNumbersFromMthRow(PhoneNumbersDAOImpl.java:108)
at com.pw.ml.Test1.main(Test1.java:18)
```

Where is the error arising?

Comment: You probably didn't inject any HibernateTemplate or SessionFactory into the DAO. Show us how you get a reference to the PhoneNumbersDAOImpl class, and how configured it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about your HQL, have you set hibernate template or session factory for your DAO? According to [HibernateDaoSupport source](http://www.koders.com/java/fid15997C9E79ECD3145CAAC25AE0B05A2BCAD0863C.aspx) you miss one.